# More efficient SQL query to update a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still new to SQL, I have the below query that works perfectly. However, as the table grows, I fear that this is now the most efficient way to accomplish this task.

```
UPDATE tblPNPStoreStock
SET [Date] = CAST('2009-05-25' AS DATETIME)
FROM tblPNPStoreStock 
WHERE [Last sold] IS NULL;
```

Someone said that I should look into a nested approach - I don't know where to start.

Comment: I guess you simply need a index on `Last sold` attribute

Comment: Well, if you want to keep only date values there is no point of keeping them in a datetime data type when we have a date data type since 2008 version. Other then that, your code seems fine. Beware of premature optimizations.

Comment: if the day you are casting is constant then you could assign it to a variable. so it does not `cast` it for each row.

Comment: Always tag the SQL Server version for questions, each version may have better solutions than the previous.

Comment: The date is going to be dynamic (Query will run from a VB app).

Comment: @RadimBača thank you, I will look into INDEX.

Comment: @TT. Noted, thank you

Comment: I don't see any need of `FROM` clause in this query, the query could be simply `UPDATE tblPNPStoreStock SET [Date] = '2009-05-25' WHERE [Last sold] Is NUll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008+ you can [create a filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes), which can index rows where `[Last sold]` is NULL:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
    fix_tblPNPStoreStock_last_sold
ON
    tblPNPStoreStock(
        [Last sold] 
    )
WHERE
    [Last sold] IS NULL;
```

This would optimize your update statement. Note that a regular index might be better, if you have different criteria based on that column.

Comment: Are you sure an index that contains only `null` values will actually make a difference? It seems strange to me...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, if that's the only case where there is a where clause on `[Last sold]` and it checks for nullness. The update statement will be able to directly select all primary keys from the filtered nonclustered index (it contains just those where `[Last sold]` is NULL).

Comment: Thanks, I would probably never think of it myself :-)